# App crashes where Microsoft 365 installed

Tags: c++, database, crash, office365, runtime

[image]A C++ app crashes (only on our develop pc's where we have also VisualStudio, in all others works fine) after few second from startup. If we run it on debug we an Kernelbase.dll Module not found exception, last call at MSO.DLL!__delayLoadHelper2(). At the moment of the crash the app already loaded all the databases it use.

Tried to update all: windows, Microsoft365, visual studio etc.
Change Provider from 12.0 to 16.0
Installed Microsoft 365 Access Runtime and Microsoft Access 2013 Runtime (with these is also impossible to use Access app)

Comment: I am seeing exactly the same issue with a Win32 C++ app of mine. Don't suppose you got anywhere with solving it? I guess it's an Office issue but no idea where i'd report the bug to Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution in Visual Studio, and go to Project>Application Properties
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmqI2.png)

Then go to Settings on the left, and you should get one or more similar errors like below:

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAiQm.png)

Click yes on all the notifications to update the settings. Compile your app and try again.